# StandardServiceRegistryBuilder and ServiceRegistry in Hibernate Framework

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to develop a simple CRUD application using Spring and Hibernate framework. I am taking help from [Hibernate Tutorials : CRUD example in hibernate](https://www.ashtpoint.com/hibernate-tutorials/crud-example-in-hibernate.html) tutorial.

In this tutorial, there is a separate class as below which is being used to create session factory.

```
package com.hibernatetest.utils;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class SessionManagerUtil {

 private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

 private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

 Configuration config = null;
 StandardServiceRegistryBuilder regBuilder = null;
 ServiceRegistry serviceReg = null;

 try {

 config = new Configuration();
 config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

 regBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
 regBuilder.applySettings(config.getProperties());

 serviceReg = regBuilder.build();

 return config.buildSessionFactory(serviceReg);

 } catch (Exception e) {
 throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e.getMessage());
 }

 }

 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
 return sessionFactory;
 }
}
```

But I don't understand why the below is being used here, what is the purpose of them.

```
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder regBuilder = null;
ServiceRegistry serviceReg = null;
```

If you can explain above that would be really helpful for me to understand it better.

Comment: What is your problem? They are hibernate api.

Answer (score 0):

```
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder regBuilder ;
ServiceRegistry serviceReg ;
```

if you write like this it will show compile time error .They are not initialized, just they are declared and you may think like they can be initialized in try since you are using them in the try block. if there is any exception in try block before initialized statement,its goes to catch block. after handling the exception,now statements after the catch block will execute, there might be a chance of using those two references after catch, since there are not initialized we cannot use them, JVM identifies these kind of issues and show error at compile time itself. That is the reason they have initialized with null reference.